# Finding transfer function of high-pass circuit

Tags: filter, transfer-function, high-pass-filter, nodal-analysis

I've already done the calculations myself, but I am getting a completely wrong answer for the poles and zeros. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. If someone could point out my mistake please I would greatly appreciate it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off \$R_{_\text{S}}+\frac1{s\,C_1}\ne\frac{s \,R_{_\text{S}}\,C_1}{s \,R_{_\text{S}}\,C_1+1}\$. Rather, \$R_{_\text{S}}+\frac1{s\,C_1}=\frac{s \,R_{_\text{S}}\,C_1+1}{s \,R_{_\text{S}}\,C_1}\$.

Next, the transfer function for this high-pass must follow this `template`:

$$\frac{v_o}{v_i}=A\cdot\frac{s}{s+\omega_{_0}}$$

In your case, \$A=\frac1{1+\frac{R_{_\text{S}}}{R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2}}\$ and \$\omega_{_0}=\frac1{C_1\,\cdot\,\left[R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\right]}\$.

You should be able to see both of these. As \$\omega\to\infty\$, the capacitor becomes a wire and you just have a voltage divider. So the value of \$A\$ should be obvious from that fact. Separately, swap the series order of \$R_{_\text{S}}\$ and \$C_1\$ and you can see that \$C_1\$ `sees` a load of \$R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\$. So \$\omega_{_0}\$ is similarly obvious.

The zero is at \$s=0\$ and the pole is at \$s=-\omega_{_0}\$.

Let's start with your first equation, which you correctly formed:

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{v_o}{v_i}&=\frac{R_1\mid\mid R_2}{R_{_\text{S}}+\frac1{s\,C_1}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)}
\\\\
&=\frac{s\,C_1\cdot\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)}{1+s\,C_1\cdot\left[R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\right]}
\\\\
&=\frac{C_1\cdot\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)}{C_1\cdot\left[R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\right]}\cdot\frac{s}{s+\frac1{C_1\cdot\left[R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\right]}}
\\\\
&=\frac{R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2}{R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)}\cdot\frac{s}{s+\frac1{C_1\cdot\left[R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\right]}}
\\\\
&=\frac{1}{1+\frac{R_{_\text{S}}}{R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2}}\cdot\frac{s}{s+\frac1{C_1\cdot\left[R_{_\text{S}}+\left(R_1\,\mid\mid \,R_2\right)\right]}}
\\\\
&=A\cdot\frac{s}{s+\omega_{_0}}
\end{align*}$$

So we come full circle back to where I started, above.

So \$f_{0}=\frac{\omega_{_0}}{2\pi}\approx 111.038\:\text{Hz}\$ and \$A\approx 0.93\approx -628\:\text{mdB}\$.

An LTspice run finds:

[image]

I couldn't get an exact \$45^\circ\$ out of it. But I bracketed it. It shows that \$111.0133\:\text{Hz}\lt f_{0}\lt 111.04525\:\text{Hz}\$.

The value of \$A\$ can be worked out by adding \$3.0103\:\text{dB}\$. Here, I would get something like \$-0.628\:\text{dB}\$. Which is about what I said, earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The transfer function determined by *periblepsis* correctly shows a zero at the origin with a pole breaking the +1 slope to 0. The gain at high frequency then plateaus slightly below 1 with the adopted components values. By using the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my last [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1960405195), you can get to the transfer function without writing a line of algebra, by dividing the original circuit in small intermediate steps you can *inspect*:

[image]

You first realize that for \$s=0\$, there is no gain as \$C_1\$ acts like a dc-block component so \$H_0\$=0. Then, you turn the excitation off - set \$V_{in}\$ to 0 V and replace it by a short circuit - and determine the time constant of this 1st-order circuit. The inverse of the time constant is the pole you want. Then, determine the high-frequency gain \$H^1\$ and apply the generalized formula I give. Factor the \$s\$-term in the numerator as well as in the denominator and you now have a transfer function expressed in a *low-entropy* form, with a gain as the leading term and an inverted pole for the most compact notation.